# Telerik RadRating missing star when zoomed out

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am having issue with RadRating control , It renders fine if the browser is zoomed to 100 %. But in chrome if the browser is zoomed 90 % or below 1 out of 5 stars will go missing.

I can see that the 5th start is there in source code but pushed to a new line and goes hidden, I checked Demo page of RadRating control  (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/rating/examples/gridrating/defaultcs.aspx) and this issue is there as well.

It will be very rare someone zooming their browser to 90 % but it will be better to make sure even when that happens control will be  rendered fine.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Take the demo page in chrome
2. Set zoom to 90%
3. Reload the page

I tried setting CSS zoom on both control and the whole body but it is not helping. Setting a CSS zoom  of 50 % on control will show all 5 stars  but then the stars will be too small. It will be great if someone can suggest me a workaround to fix this.

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Report the issue directly to telerik and they will work with you on a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to hack the code by setting width of RadRating div from 104px to 112px using jQuery on page load. Still it will be great to know a nice and neat way to fix this.

UPDATE:

Also I was suggested a much neater solution using CSS in Telerik forum.

.RadRating
    {
        width: 112px !important;
    }

[My Post in Telerik Forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/rating/radrating-missing-star-when-zoomed-out.aspx)